# First-In-First-out reader writer Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, fifo

Here we built a concurrent program in Java where we simulate a database which we read from and write into it. We have 20 readers which read simultaneously and 2 writers which don't.

The readers start reading and after they finish, writers start writing which cause starvation to writers.

The output I get:

```
Reader 15 started reading
Reader 5 started reading
Reader 2 started reading
Reader 7 started reading
Reader 15 finished reading
Reader 5 finished reading
Reader 16 started reading
...
...
Writer 21 started writing
Writer 21 finished writing
Writer 20 started writing
Writer 20 finished writing
```

So, I've been trying to implement FIFO order to this program in order to kill this starvation. for example, the output should be R1, W1, R2, R3, R4, W2 (R -- reader, W-- writer). I am stuck at this point and I don't know to whether change my algoritm or not. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            runDB(20, 2, new BetterDB());
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored){}
    }

    static void runDB(int readersAmount, int writersAmount, DB database) throws InterruptedException {
        assert readersAmount > 0;
        assert writersAmount > 0;

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[readersAmount + writersAmount];

        for (int i = 0; i < readersAmount; i++){
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Reader(database, i));
        }
        for (int i = readersAmount; i <  readersAmount + writersAmount; i++){
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Writer(database, i));
        }

        for (Thread thread : threads){
            thread.start();
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads){
            thread.join();
        }
    }
}

interface DB {
    void read(int readerID) throws InterruptedException;
    void write(int writerId);
}

class BetterDB implements DB {
    long READ_TIME = 500; // milliseconds
    long WRITE_TIME = 1000; // milliseconds

    int readers = 0;

    @Override
    public void read(int readerID) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            readers++;
            System.out.printf("Reader %d started reading\n", readerID);
        }

        try {
            ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
            Thread.sleep(random.nextLong(READ_TIME));
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}

        synchronized (this) {
            readers--;
            System.out.printf("Reader %d finished reading\n", readerID);
            if (readers == 0) {
                this.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(int writerId) {
        try{
            while(readers > 0){
                this.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}

        System.out.printf("Writer %d started writing\n", writerId);
        try{
            ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
            Thread.sleep(random.nextLong(WRITE_TIME));
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}

        System.out.printf("Writer %d finished writing\n", writerId);
    }
}


class Reader implements Runnable {
    final long READER_DELAY = 500; // milliseconds
    private final DB database;
    private int id;

    Reader(DB database, int id){
        this.database = database;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
            Thread.sleep(random.nextLong(READER_DELAY));
            database.read(id);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    }
}

class Writer implements Runnable {
    final long WRITER_DELAY = 400; // milliseconds
    private final DB database;
    private int id;

    Writer(DB database, int id){
        this.database = database;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
            Thread.sleep(random.nextLong(WRITER_DELAY));
            database.write(id);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to have some writes and reads mixed ?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand what you're trying, you want your writers to be able to pause the readers so they actually have a chance to write?

Right now, they're being overwhelmed. The readers can all stay busy all they want because there are 20, and they can all run at the same time, and the likelihood they'll all pause long enough for a writer to grab the synchronized lock is very very low.

It sounds like you need to implement more complicated locking, such as a "request two write" lock. You can have your writers increment the lock and then decrement it when they're done. The readers would need similar logic that the writers have checking to see if there's a request to write lock.